# Jquery contains multiple values

Tags: jquery

Im using Jquery datepicker and also a PhP calender in my webpage. I want to use the same javascript array as in the datepicker function in my PHP calender to change the class of the "not available" dates. jquery contains works fine for a single date, but is it possible to do the same with an array?

Code that works (1 value):

```
$("td:contains('21')").css("color", "red");
```

The ideal situation is to do the same for all TD with an array, something like:

```
var unavailableDates1 = ["21","23","25"];
$("td:contains(unavailableDates1)").css("color", "red");
```

help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop an array like this:

```
var unavailableDates1 = ["21","23","25"]; 
for(var i=0;i<unavailableDate1.length;i++){
    $("td:contains("+unavailableDates1[i]+")").css("color", "red");
}
```

Comment: hmmm, good idea! But not working, i think because of the +i+ in the contains, thats not the value in the array but the counter of the loop. Am i thinking correct?

Comment: @JilcoTigchelaar oops, my bad... fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td:contains("21"), td:contains("22"), td:contains("23")').css("color", "red");
```